# Laravel sanctum API, retrieve the token for use in view components

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-sanctum

Here is the context. I have two sites using the same domain.

The first using Laravel and view components The second is an "API", I use Laravel Sanctum. This API has a single user. Later, there will be a third site using this same API as well.

The API authentication system works perfectly. When I switch from Postman my user, my token is returned.

I'm wondering about token retrieval and usage on my first site using vue components.

My idea was to store API user login credentials in my .env file and retrieve the token in controllers where I use vue components.

Another solution would be to fetch my token on each call to the API, but that could be cumbersome.

Finally store the token at the user's connection and reuse it but where to store it, in session, in cookies,... Security level is not ideal.

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Comment: hi Damien, i didnt quite catch it. **This API has a single user** - does this meant every single user on your first website will share the same access key to the second website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default thing to do to use token as a bearer token from the front end is as following

1. login attempt to backend and you will get the token to authenticate your request later.
2. store it using vuex store in you user store
3. then do your API request using that token
4. destroy the token after logout

if you are concerning about security, well the token should have expiration time and the token itself should be destroyed from the backend when the user is logged out. Every time the user do the login, new token will be created for them

Answer (score 0):

If your API authentication is working properly, Then you've to store your token on the database every time the user logs in. And delete on some other occasions. To store your token on database every time the user logs in use the following code:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Invalid credential'
        ], 401);
    }

    $user = User::where('email', $request['email'])->firstOrFail();
    //store the hashed token on db and return plain text token for the user
    $token = $user->createToken('token_name')->plainTextToken;

    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $token,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
    ]);
}
```

I took the code from [here](https://easycodesolution.com/2022/06/11/laravel-sanctum-api-authentication/)